# Pass ViewModel to Controller using JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

I have problem passing ViewModel data to the Controller. Can you please help me?

Here is part of code with problem ... all possibilities are not working and in the Controller the value is still null... :-(

My ViewModel:

```
public class NabidkaCreateViewModel
{
    public List<Items> ItemsList = new List<Items>();

    public Guid? ItemsGlobalId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemsGlobal> ItemsGlobal { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateOffer", "Offers", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "Redirectfunction" }))
{  
    @Html.DropDownList("ItemsGlobalId", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "PolozkaSelector", @class = "form-control" })

    <input id="PridatPolozku" type="button" value="Přidat" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" />

    <div id="result" class="col-md-12 h5">
        @Html.Partial("_PolozkyNabidky", Model)
    </div>
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $("#PridatPolozku").click(function () {
        var Id = $("#PolozkaSelector").val();
        var parsedData = ( ItemsGlobalId: Id,  N: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ItemsList)));

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("AddPolozka", "Offers")",
            data: parsedData,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
            alert("Return OK... ";

        }
    });
    });
});
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddPolozka(string ItemsGlobalId, NabidkaCreateViewModel N)
    {
        Guid IDtemp = new Guid(ItemsGlobalId); 

        ItemsGlobal IG = new ItemsGlobal();
        Items I = new Items();  
        IG = await db.ItemsGlobals.FindAsync(IDtemp);

        I.NadpisCZ = IG.NadpisCZ;
        I.NadpisEN = IG.NadpisEN;
        I.NadpisDE = IG.NadpisDE;
        I.TextCZ = IG.TextCZ;
        I.TextEN = IG.TextEN;
        I.TextDE = IG.TextDE;  
        I.Cena = IG.Cena;
        I.DobaVyroby = IG.DobaVyroby;
        I.SlevaHodnota = 0;
        I.JednotkyId = IG.JednotkyId;           
        I.KurzMenaId = IG.KurzMenaId;          

        N.ItemsList.Add(I);

        return PartialView("_PolozkyNabidky", N);             
    }
```

Comment: IMO @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ItemsList)) will not produce a convertible NabidkaCreateViewModel object. Either you will have to define a binder or change the client side JS object representation of a NabidkaCreateViewModel.

Comment: Firstly it would need to be `var parsedData = { ItemsGlobalId: Id, ...}`, but what is the point of `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ItemsList))`? You would only be sending back exactly the same data you sent to the view in the first place - just get it again in the `AddPolozka` method

Comment: Thank you. Script is now:  var parsedData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); - ItemsGlobalId is now part of Model (ViewModel). In controller are input parameters of AddPoloza without: string ItemsGlobalId... ... and all working great. I need only restore ViewModel from controller back using json and update data of ViewModel